# how to convert a shape key animation to a fluid?

Tags: animation, node-editor, physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation

So I just finished this tutorial by Tutor4u using shape keys to convert a rolling ball into a wine glass. after that animation I would like to convert the wine glass into a fluid. The problem is I cant seem to get the wine glass to interact with the fluid physics. I can easily get it to work with regular objects in separate files no problem.

here is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx5L8K99j10&t=1476s

This is my third day with blender, so I am probably missing something very simple.
I suspect that I am not setting some time parameter to account for the animation in the beginning, or that the fluid portion doesn't recognize the wine glass because it switched materials.

Id appreciate any feedback. this is driving me nuts!!

Comment: Hi, welcome. That tutorial doesn't seem to use fluid physics at all... it is just a shape morphing achieved by shape keys keyframe animation. Which "fluid physics" are you referring to? Did you try another setup which includes fluids? You say you wish to "convert" a modeled shape (the wine part) in a "wine fluid"... if you widh the "wine" to become a fluid simulation, after being morphed from a sphere...maybe.. faking it! create another scene with just the same transparent glass, containing a red wine fluid simulation, and then join the first animation result to the second... no, not easy.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @m.ardito To be clear, at the end of the animation, i want the glass and wine to convert to a fluid and fall downwards into a puddle. this is not in the tutorial.
I have watched other tutorials on turning objects into fluid and its quite simple. however I can not get it to work in this situation.
I tried duplicating the glass, but it just disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now it's clearer. If I got what you mean, I tried a (much simplified and rough) example.

I started from a simple sphere, set basis shape key,

[image]

added another, shaped it like a glass extruding vertices,

[image]

had the morphing effect.

[image]

Then set the morphed glass object as fluid,

[image]

added a surrounding big cube, set it to fluid domain,

[image]

and baked the domain.

[image]

When it finished, I hid the original glass shape, keeping only the domain visible. Now it seems to splash as you expect... does it?

[image]

Is this not working for you? Did you forget to bake? Of course I used rough fluid settings, you'll need at least much finer domain resolution.

Comment: thank you for persisting. That is precisely what I am trying to do. Have the animation play then drop into a puddle. however, It is still is not working. I should note that my animation is in cycles render, but I have also tried blender render without success. Usually after baking the fluid simulation, the domain will disappear. but mine remains a solid box. 
I am wondering if I should recreate a second file of the wine glass and world, render a fluid simulation in a separate file, then stitch them, together in the video editor.

Comment: something else that might help.. I just read that fluid simulations always start at the first frame. this might be the issue.  how could i set a keyframe to start the fluid simulation after the transformation animation? Thanks again in advance

Comment: Ive added a uv sphere (fluid) above the glass (obstacle) and the fluid simulation works fine except it does not interact with the glass. 
soooooo. it looks like the glass is immune to fluid simulations lol
is there a way to duplicate the glass as an object (without keyframes etc attached)?

edit.. I can start the fluid simulation at a given fame by inserting a negative offset value but the cube wont become transparent until that specified frame

Comment: first, render engine counts nothing here, second, the domain usually does not "disappear": it _becomes_ the fluid sim, the initial domain shape represente the limits. but in last comment you say "fluid simulation works"... but skips obstacle interaction... I'm a bit lost on what you have working or not, now...

Comment: I understand that the domain becomes the "parametric domain for the simulation" just trying to keep things simple. I fixed this by keyframing the visibility 

What does not work : the wine glass interacting with fluid simulations
what does work: any other object with fluid simulations 

if i set a sphere above the glass to fluid, and the glass to obstacle, the fluid will pass straight through the glass. 

does that make sense?

Comment: Ok it does interact, though not 100% realistically.  I just had to turn up the resolution.
https://i.gyazo.com/2bd85597c4de9e8e7a952b2e73239ff9.gif