# Blender shape fluid to a shape

Tags: mesh, modifiers, particles, transforms, fluid-simulation

I have been searching alot for a way to shape a fluid animation to a solid shape

Kinda like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ9HogEWcT0

I have found this solution

[how to convert a shape key animation to a fluid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77056/how-to-convert-a-shape-key-animation-to-a-fluid)

problem is I need to have 1 part of the mesh shaped solid and the other side liquid like while having some growth **(like in the video)**

Any idea how I can achieve this effect?

Comment: The YouTube link is no longer valid making this question effectively unanswerable without additional information.